# How to set the request body on the client side

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest

Suppose I have the following web method using C# and .NET:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplage="/users", Method="POST")]
[OperationContract]
public User AddNewUser(User u);
```

It is expected that when you implement POST web method you will accept a request body as part of the incoming HTTP request message. The parameter u is expected to be deserialized from the incoming HTTP message body.

My question is: how do we set this request body on the client side ? It's got to be set somewhere. It really confuses me.

**Besides if I added "ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json" to WebInvoke, how can I deserialize from the returned json string into the User object ?**

Thanks.

Comment: If these answers helped you, then please take the time to award the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't reveal what you have tried. If you are using .net on the client then you can use the [**DataContractSerializer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) to get the serialized data.

You can then use an **[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)** with the method set to **POST**.
Add the serialized data to the web request and use the GetResponse() method.

Alternatively you could use [Fiddlr](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to test your web service using requests that you create. It gives you a concise view of exactly what is going up to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a POST request to your WCF Rest method:

```
    private string UseHttpWebApproach<T>(string serviceUrl, string resourceUrl, string method, T requestBody)
    {
            string responseMessage = null;                
            var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = method;
            }

            if(method == "POST" && requestBody != null)
            {                   
                byte[] requestBodyBytes = ToByteArrayUsingJsonContractSer(requestBody);                
                request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);
            }

            if (request != null)
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                        responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
                }
            }
            return responseMessage;
    }

    private static byte[] ToByteArrayUsingJsonContractSer<T> (T requestBody)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        var serializer1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        var ms1 = new MemoryStream();
        serializer1.WriteObject(ms1, requestBody);
        ms1.Position = 0;
        var reader = new StreamReader(ms1);
        bytes = ms1.ToArray();
        return bytes;
    }
```

Now Assuming your User object as shown below:

```
Public Class User
{
    Public int UserId  {get;set;}
    Public string UserName {get;set;}
    Public string Password  {get;set;}
}
```

The to call the above method i do:

```
User objUser = new objUser();
objUser.Username = "Test";
objUser.Password = "Test";
UseHttpWebApproach<User>(serviceBaseUrl, "users", "POST", objUser);
```

Comment: Your responseMessage is a string. How can I get a User Object out of it? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the DataContractSerializer to Deserialize the string data into your object instance.

Comment: If the request body contains some sensitive data like user password, how can I ensure security?

Comment: You can use Https with an ssl on your server. If you really wanted to sledgehammer the security you could also encrypt the password with a time sensitive hash issued by the server, maybe something based on the IP of the user, but that is outside the scope of this question.